Submit works only with Enter key
I have a strange problem. In my login page, I can successfully login after entering user/pw but only when pressing the Enter key. The Login button is not clickable.
Actually, after trying some console.log/alert test buttons, even on different pages, it seems that no button works in my app.
Any ideas?
My Next.js version is 14.2.5.
Login page:
"use client";

import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from "react-dom";
import { authenticate } from "@/app/actions";

export default function LoginForm() {
  const [errorMessage, dispatch] = useFormState(authenticate, undefined);
  return (
    <form action={dispatch} className="space-y-3">
      <div className="flex-1 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 px-6 pb-4 pt-8">
        <h1 className=" mb-3 text-xl">Please log in to continue.</h1>
        <div className="w-full">
          <div>
            <label className="mb-3 mt-5 block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900" htmlFor="email">
              Username / Email
            </label>
            <div className="relative">
              <input
                className="peer block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 py-[9px] pl-4 text-sm outline-2 placeholder:text-gray-500"
                id="email"
                type="text"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Enter your username or email"
                required
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="mt-4">
            <label className="mb-3 mt-5 block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900" htmlFor="password">
              Password
            </label>
            <div className="relative">
              <input
                className="peer block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 py-[9px] pl-4 text-sm outline-2 placeholder:text-gray-500"
                id="password"
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Enter password"
                required
                // minLength={6}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <LoginButton />
        <div className="flex h-8 items-end space-x-1" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
          {errorMessage && (
            <>
              <p className="text-sm text-red-500">{errorMessage}</p>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

function LoginButton() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();
  return (
    <button
      type="submit"
      className="w-full cursor-pointer rounded-lg border border-slate-300 bg-orange-600 py-2 
      text-sm font-semibold text-white first-line:mt-4"
      aria-disabled={pending}
    >
      Log in
    </button>
  );
}


Have you checked what pending is?

const { pending } = useFormStatus();

It's using useFormStatus from import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from "react-dom";

Have you checked what the value of pending is with console.log() to see if it's true, which would make the button disabled? Get in the habit of debugging your own code! This might not be the issue, but it's something you should check.

Sure, I did that. It's false. I also removed the whole disabling logic and left a simple button. No button works, even the simplest one.

I would also edit your question to include you're using an unreleased version of React. But this code seems to work fine when clicking the button with 19.0.0-beta-26f2496093-20240514. Are there Javascript errors in the console? https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gracious-satoshi-29gk77?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A86%2C20

I am not using an unreleased version. As I wrote, I am using Next.js 14.2.5, which has React 18.3.1 which is the latest official release, as of now.

No Javascript errors in the console, I'm afraid...

react-dom@18.3.1 does not export a function called useFormState. Try changing the codesandbox version package.json react and react-dom to ^18.3.1 and note that it errors.

Regardless, something seems incomplete about your question. It is not possible to use that function with the React version you're claiming. The linked codesandbox with the correct React version works fine. It's likely there's something incorrect outside of the code you're showing us. Are you using two versions of React? Is there global CSS disabling buttons? Is something globally swallowing errors? Try enabling "pause on caught exceptions" in the Chrome debugger. It's not possible to answer this question as-is because this question appears impossible.

Andy, I've tried upgrading to the latest RC version and it still doesn't work. I will try to do some cleaning up and further investigate what's going on in my environment. I'll update. Thanks.

@AndyRay, as you've suggested the problem was elsewhere - it was the sidebar element which had a "w-screen". I removed it and everything is OK now. If you'd like to copy your suggestions as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!
